# unauthorized HTTP request when using python requests

Tags: python, rest, api, http-status-code-401

When I try the REST API with curl, it is working like a charm. The code that works is given below:

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:####My Key####" \
"https://api.eu-gb.natural-language-understanding.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/4b490a19-9cd0-4e9b-9f71-c7ce59f9d7df/v1/analyze?version=2019-07-12" \
--request POST \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{
  "text": "I love apples! I do not like oranges.",
  "features": {
    "sentiment": {
      "targets": [
        "apples",
        "oranges",
        "broccoli"
      ]
    },
    "keywords": {
      "emotion": true
    }
  }
}'
```

But I'm not getting authenticated when I'm doing same thing in my Python code. not sure how to use the "-u" in the python code.

```
import requests

WATSON_NLP_URL = "https://api.eu-gb.natural-language-understanding.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/4b490a19-9cd0-4e9b-9f71-c7ce59f9d7df/v1/analyze?version=2019-07-12"
WATSONAPIKEY = "XXXX"
params = {"apikey":WATSONAPIKEY}
json_to_nlp = {
  "text": "I love apples! I do not like oranges.",
  "features": {
    "sentiment": {
      "targets": [
        "apples",
        "oranges",
        "broccoli"
      ]
    },
    "keywords": {
      "emotion": "true"
    }
  }
}

r = requests.post(url=WATSON_NLP_URL, json=json_to_nlp, params=params)
data = r.json()
print (r)
```

I get Unauthorized (401) response:

```
<Response [401]>
```

Comment: In the first request (curl) the data is sent as Authorization header, while in your python post request it's sent as a simple param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For curl, `-u` is to add a basic auth header.

So you would like to build request like this:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

WATSON_NLP_URL = "https://api.eu-gb.natural-language-understanding.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/4b490a19-9cd0-4e9b-9f71-c7ce59f9d7df/v1/analyze?version=2019-07-12"
WATSONAPIKEY = "XXXX"
json_to_nlp = {
  "text": "I love apples! I do not like oranges.",
  "features": {
    "sentiment": {
      "targets": [
        "apples",
        "oranges",
        "broccoli"
      ]
    },
    "keywords": {
      "emotion": "true"
    }
  }
}

r = requests.post(url=WATSON_NLP_URL, json=json_to_nlp, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('apikey', WATSONAPIKEY))
data = r.json()
print (r)
```